# Почему в песне уточка «ква-ква»?

Tags: литература, междометие, фольклор

В «Братьях Карамазовых» приводится текст, вероятно, народной песни:

```
Свинушка хрю-хрю, хрю-хрю,
Телочка му-му, му-му,
Уточка ква-ква, ква-ква,

Гусынька га-га, га-га.
Курочка по сенюшкам похаживала,
Тюрю-рю, рю-рю, выговаривала,
Ай, ай, выговаривала!
```

Cоответствия логичные, кроме уточки; почему она в песне квакает?

Comment: _Заметки на полях: в итальянском языке уточка квакает (qua-qua), а лягушечка крякает (cra-cra)._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наиболее распространена разновидность утки под названием кря**ква** (даже в прудах Петербурга именно такие). Орнитологи воспроизводят голос самки в брачный период как "**куак**" (см. Википедию; ссылки там на этот предмет - русскоязычные, что важно). Составители кроссвордов полагают, что эта якобы особенная утка и крякает, и квакает. Сочинители же песен (хотя бы в силу крестьянской малограмотности) могли не знать об "общепринятом" для уток литературном "крякании" и полагаться на собственное слуховое восприятие.